# MongoDB on Raspberry Pi fails to load

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, debian, raspbian

I just installed Mongodb on my Raspberry Pi 3 using the regular `sudo apt install mongodb`, which gave no errors. I then checked the status:

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-02-17 08:53:47 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 11569 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 11569 (code=exited, status=14)

Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4a9a0) [0x7680e9a0]
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: Fri Feb 17 08:53:47.612 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: Fri Feb 17 08:53:47.613 Backtrace:
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: 0x664160 0x16e370 0x765e2180 0x765e0f70
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x1c) [0x664160]
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x2a0) [0x16e370]
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0x765e2180]
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi mongod[11569]: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x765e0f70]
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mongodb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Feb 17 08:53:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit mongodb.service entered failed state.
```

And I tried starting it with `sudo service mongodb start`, but in the logs (using `sudo journalctl -f`) I only get this:

```
Feb 17 08:53:58 raspberrypi sudo[11586]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service mongodb start
Feb 17 08:53:58 raspberrypi sudo[11586]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting An object/document-oriented database...
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi sudo[11586]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: Fri Feb 17 08:53:59.391 terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: 0x664160 0x16d954 0x768649a0
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x1c) [0x664160]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x54) [0x16d954]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4a9a0) [0x768649a0]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: Fri Feb 17 08:53:59.393 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: Fri Feb 17 08:53:59.394 Backtrace:
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: 0x664160 0x16e370 0x76638180 0x76636f70
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x1c) [0x664160]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x2a0) [0x16e370]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0x76638180]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi mongod[11608]: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x76636f70]
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mongodb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Feb 17 08:53:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit mongodb.service entered failed state.
```

I don't really understand these errors. Does anybody else know what's going on?

Comment: seems like there is something wrong with your libstdc++ : /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 . You can look if this file exist and if the user permissions are ste properly.

Comment: @jdesesquelles - Any idea what that is, or how I can fix or reinstall it?

Comment: First of all have you configure a log path in  `mongod.cfg` for example  `#where to log
logpath=D:\MongoDatas\log\mongod.log` and then have a look to the log.

Comment: Running mongodb on an ARM architecture with 1GB of RAM is quite an extreme case. Prepare to deep learn the DB and to google a lot. This particular error might come from locale misconfiguration. Ensure the locale you set in `export LANG=` has been generated in `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: @kramer65 this is the standard c++library. I assume you simply need to install libstdc++. apt-get install libstdc++ on ubuntu for example, yum on red hat and so on ..